# Recurring Payments paypal inserting data in database

Tags: database, codeigniter, paypal

I have successful integrate `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` method that will recurre payment from the client. Now what I need to do is:

After every month of reccuring payment I need to insert data in my database table. Is there anything that I get response from paypal after the payment is done?
Or how can I insert data in my database after each time period?

Thank you all for reading my post. I looking forward for your post - any suggestion are most welcome.

Regards,
anstrangelover

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the APIs and such that paypal offers:

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/instant-payment-notification

https://www.paypal.com/ipn

> IPN can send notifications for these transactions:
>
> ```
> Instant payments, including Express Checkout and direct credit card payments
> eCheck payments and pending, completed, or denied status payments
> Pending payments
> Recurring payments and subscriptions
> Authorizations
> Disputes, chargebacks, reversals, and refunds
> ```

Comment: thank you for ur post its really helpful :). m going throough it

Answer (score 0):

I use this library: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PayPal_Lib/

It works pretty well for me. I created an order_model which maps to a table match the fields I want from the IPN, then I just made a controller with a method like this:

```
function ipn(){
    $this->load->library("paypal_lib");
    $res = $this->paypal_lib->ipn();

    $response = print_r($res, TRUE);
    log_message('error', $response);

    if(isset($res["error"])) {
        log_message('error', 'fail');
        return;
    }
    if($res["verified"]) {
        log_message('error', 'verified');
        $res["payment"] = "paypal";
        $new_order = $this->order_model->create($res["data"]);  
        log_message('error', 'created order: '.$new_order['id']);           
    } else {
        log_message('error', 'no error, but not verified?');
    }
}
```